# Draw html page using the QPainter

Tags: html, qt, printing, qwebview

How i can draw html page?

```
QWebView *view = new QWebView();
view.Load(Url("http://www.google.com"));

QPrinter printer = new Qprinter();
```

How I can draw this view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you simply want to print the page, just use the `QWebView::print(QPrinter *)` method.

If you want to draw the view to an arbitrary paint device, use `QWebView::render(QPaintDevice *)`.  This method is available on any `QWidget` subclass.

Comment: I want to print via Microsoft Xps Printer. 
QPrinter.setPrinterName("Microsoft Xps Printer");

Answer (score 0):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{          QWebView view = new QWebView(this);
           //Set settings
           view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavaEnabled, true);
           view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);
           view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptCanOpenWindows, false);
           view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptCanAccessClipboard, false);
           view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::AutoLoadImages, true);
           //Load URl
           view->page()->mainFrame()->load(QUrl("http://www.habrahabr.ru"));
           //Connect signal loadFinished
           connect(view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), SLOT(finishLoading(bool)))
}

void MainWindow::finishLoading(bool)
 {
    //Printing
    QPrinter *printer = new QPrinter(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    printer->setPrinterName("Microsoft XPS Document Writer");
    printer->setOutputFileName("out.xps");
    view->page()->mainFrame()->print(printer);
 }
```

Almost everything works, except for small parts. Do not tell my how to configure? FontFamily, FontSize, footer and header, link...